# Within how many days do I get refunded the cost of a reservation cancelled because of schedule change by Wizz Air?

Tags: tickets, refunds, wizz-air

I received an email from Wizz Air about a schedule change to my flight. There were three options to choose from and I opted for cancellation of both outgoing and return flights and receiving 120% credit for further bookings in my Wizz account (full credit + 20% extra). After choosing this option there was a message on the screen stating that I'll get a reply to my request by email in a couple of work days.

How many days exactly will the processing of my request approval take?

How long does the process of refunding take?

If I get the refund, can I purchase a ticket for the same flight again if needed?

Comment: How long has it been since? These things typically don't go very quickly as the airline has no incentive to be in a hurry. And you are free to purchase whatever flight you wish, however given price developments, you might be better off buying tickets before you get the refund/credit.

Comment: Are you getting a credit of 120% as you first wrote or a full refund of the ticket price plus a 20% credit as you wrote second.   If you are getting a credit then there is no refund only a credit to use for future tickets.

Comment: How long before your travel time were you told about the schedule change? The rules differ according to whether you had more than two weeks of warning, between one and two weeks, or less than one week.

Comment: @pnuts I got the email today and I also got refunded 120% in my wizz account. It took 3 days which is quite good.

Comment: I thank you for your answers and comments. Happy holidays! :)

Answer (score 4):

By the EU air passenger rights regulation, they should have offered you the option of refunding the full price of the ticket in cash (or bank transfer etc) within **seven days**.

Apparently you accepted being refunded in credit-for-future-tickets rather than cash, in return for a 20% extra reimbursement. This seems to moot the "within seven days" limits that applies to cash refunds, and all in all it may not be in your interest unless you have concrete plansto spend those credits in the foreseeable future.

Note that your acceptance of future credit instead of cash is *not binding* on you unless *signed* by you -- the regulation explicitly requires a signature.

Answer (score 3):

Wizz Air have told you you will:

> get a reply to my request by email in a couple of work days

and they should know better than anyone how long they will take. So anticipate something by Wednesday at the latest.

I would expect the e-mail to be confirmation that your account *has* been credited, so no extra time for the "refunding" step.

> I purchase a ticket for the same flight again if needed?

While it is possible Wizz Air may block you from doing so there is (a) no reason for them to and (b) nobody else will. However you would be starting a new booking and it is possible the cost will have gone up relative to your earlier booking - perhaps by more than 20%.